# Django/DRF Pagination using paginate_queryset doesn't return key, value but only keys in result

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've added pagination handling on one of my views using `PageNumberPagination` from DRF, using the `paginate_queryset` method works only after converting the result dict to a tuple, it's structure is like the following:

```
{
   "key": {"other": "dict inside"},
   "key2": {"other": "dict inside"},
   "key3": {"other": "dict inside"},
}
```

Pretty simple struct, the problem is that the result does return the correct data, but only their keys, I would like the result data to be key, value as the above structure instead of just keys.

Is there an easy way of doing that?

For reference I also already override `PageNumberPagination` with a custom class like this:

```
class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'controller': {
                'count': self.page.paginator.count,
                'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
                'next': self.get_next_link(),
            },
            'results': data
        })
```

And in my view to paginate:

```
class ApiView(APIView, CustomPagination):

    page_size = 10

    def get(self, request):
        # [...]
        pagination = self.paginate_queryset(tuple(result), request, view=self)
        return self.get_paginated_response(pagination)
```

Where `result` is the original dict mentionned above converted to a tuple.

Comment: After trying a bit to override django's methods I've came up with a temporary solution that isn't ideal, changing my structure to be a list of dict like `[{"id": "key1", "other": "dict inside"}, {"id": "key2", "other": "dict inside"}, {"id": "key3", "other": "dict inside"}]` with a new param in `paginate_queryset` called `identifier` which would be `id` for the above dict, then my custom method extract the `identifier` and create a structure like in my quest, I can share the method if someone is interested. Although I am still interested in a cleaner way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying stuff for a bit (read the comment bellow my question for dirty way) I upgraded my custom method to be more generic and convenient than the `identifier` thing.

So basically the `paginate_queryset` gets a new arg: `subdata` which is optional and necessary only (and if you want a key, value result) if the data given has the key, value struct I shown in the initial question.

That way the original results that returns a list is still preserved.

Here's my way of doing it overriding `paginate_queryset`:

```
def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, subdata=None, view=None):
    page_size = self.get_page_size(request)

    if not page_size:
        return None

    paginator = self.django_paginator_class(queryset, page_size)
    page_number = request.query_params.get(self.page_query_param, 1)

    if page_number in self.last_page_strings:
        page_number = paginator.num_pages

    try:
        self.page = paginator.page(page_number)

        if subdata:

            formatted_result = {}

            # Use subdata to get each page items' data
            for item in self.page.object_list:
                formatted_result[item] = subdata[item]

            # Check formatted_result contain actual result before returning
            if formatted_result:
                return formatted_result

            return None

        # Normal behavior of DRF paginate_queryset
        else:
            return list(self.page)

    except InvalidPage as error:
        # Raise the error the way you want here
```

It's not the best way, as the best way would be to override django's paginator class to support key values structs directly. But this method at least preserve the normal bahavior while working properly.